# Android widgets: addView not working with RemoteViews object

Tags: android, widget, remoteview

I want to add textviews to my widget on runtime. I saw many tutorials where RemoteViews object calls addView method to add a view to some layout.

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);
TextView t = new TextView(context);
views.addView(R.id.view_container, t);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, views);
```

But addView method shows this error: The method addView(int, RemoteViews) is undefined for the type RemoteViews.True, this method is defined for the ViewGroup class, but why is it working for everyone then? And is there a way to add textviews to some RemoteViews on runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the signature [`RemoteViews.addView(int, RemoteViews)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html#addView%28int,%20android.widget.RemoteViews%29)?

You seem to have a `TextView` as the second parameter.

Something like this should work:

```
RemoteViews remoteViewToAdd = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), LAYOUT_ID);
...
views.addView(R.id.view_container, remoteViewToAdd);
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected the parameters and stil get the same error: The method addView(int, RemoteViews) is undefined for the type RemoteViews. Since addView is only defined for the ViewGroup and RemoteViews is not it's descendant maybe I should somehow cast RemoteViews to ViewGroup. But why does it work for everyone else without it then?

Comment: `RemoteViews.addView(int, RemoteViews)` was added in API level 7. I'm assuming you're using that level or higher?

Comment: Fixed. I was targeting 1.6. Thank you!